# I want to do something after users voted

Tags: users

I want to do something after users voted. I know I can do it by using `hook_nodeapi('view')` , but I just want to add my action while a vote is being inserted in the database table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're most probably after VoteAPI integration with Rules: [Voting Rules](http://drupal.org/project/voting_rules)

It enables you to configure actions to occur when a user submits a vote, when a user deletes a vote, and when the results of a vote are calculated. Currently, Voting Rules supports votes on nodes, users, and comments.